# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-dialogfragment

I use an ArrayAdapter in a DialogFragment, that work on Android 4.0 and more but not in 2.3.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    Spinner spReglement;
    spReglement = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.listReglements);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapterList.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.customspinner);
    spReglement.setAdapter(adapterList);

    HashMap<Integer, String> mapReglement = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    mapReglement.put(-1, "");
    adapterList.add("");
    for(int i=0; i<alReglement.size();i++){
        String libelle = String.valueOf(alReglement.get(i).get("Libelle"));         
        mapReglement.put(i, libelle);
        adapterList.add(libelle);           
    }
    builder.setView(view)
           .setPositiveButton("Valider", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFSE.this);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFSE.this);
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();

}
```

My Layout "dialog" contains 3 EditText and 1 Spinner, my layout "customspinner" constains only a TextView.

When I execute my app on Android 2.3 I have the following exception :
FATAL EXCEPTION : com.mypackage.myapss.mainThread
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
...

Don't now if it's useful but I use the android support v4 library in my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this ArrayAdapter Constructor.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects);
```

***EDIT:***

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  R.layout.customspinnerregul, R.id.tvcustomspinner, al)
```

Comment: I have read that in others post but I don't understand how to use it. For example I have try the following : ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, R.layout.tvcustomspinner, al);
Where R.layout.tvcustomspinner is my TextView in "customspinnerregul.xml" and al is my ArrayList that contains all String I need in my adapter, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I have try this solution before ... but with a misspelling ! That work now, thanks for your help :)